# QGIS 3.10.0 SCP SSL Errors Downloading Landsat Mac OSX 10.14 (Mojave)

Tags: qgis, osx, ssl, ssl-error

Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (SCP) throws an SSL error when trying to download or preview Landsat images.

Looking for a workaround, this has been addressed for Windows users but not Mac.

https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#error-56-ssl-connection-error-unable-to-download-sentinel-2-images-why

I would imagine it is related to the Python installation that is bundled with QGIS and security settings on Mojave, it may be an issue that has been solved for other plugins.

> ERROR exception: 
>   url:https://ims.cr.usgs.gov/browse/landsat_8_c1/2019/019/030/LC08_L1TP_019030_20191011_20191011_01_RT.jpg